# Fitting a 3d points of an arc to a circle (regression in Python)

Tags: python, geometry, scipy, regression, least-squares

I am relatively new to python. My problem is as follows

I have a set of noisy data points (x,y,z) on an arbitrary plane that forms a 2d arc. 
I would like a best fit circle through these points and return: center (x,y,z), radius, and residue.

How do I go about this problem using scipy in python. I could solve this using an Iterative method and writing the entire code for it. However, is there a way to best fit a circle using leastsq in python? and then finding Center and Radius?

Thanks
Owais

Comment: Is the arbitrary plane known in advance, or do you have to determine that as well?  If the latter, you'll need to fit some additional parameters to determine the plane, even if you only report the center, radius, and residuals.

Comment: @JimLewis The arbitrary plane is known in advance. I had projected my 3d data points onto this best fit plane. However, now I would like a best fit circle to those project points on this best fitted plane.

Comment: If you know the plane in advance (as in your response to the question from JimLewis), then 3 points in the plane uniquely describe a circle - there's no need to mess around with any least squares algorithm (see [CIRCLE THROUGH THREE POINTS](http://www.tpub.com/content/engineering/14069/css/14069_146.htm) for a diagram of the geometric construction - you just need to take some differences and square roots). If you have a radius of uncertainty for each point and want to generate a radius of uncertainty for the circle center then it's more complicated - but you still don't need any statistics.

Comment: @Peter I actually have ~590 coordinates forming an approximate arc. I need a circular arc that best fits those coordinates and its radius and the residue.

Comment: Thanks - now it is clear that you have (x,y,z) coordinates for *each* datapoint. [This paper](http://www.infogoaround.org/JBook/LeastSquaresCircle.pdf) describes a method for finding a circle which fits an arbitrary (finite) set of planar points in the least squares sense, although it does not discuss residue and so may require a bit of adaptation for your application.

Answer (score 5):

The scipy-cookbook has a long section on fitting circles:
http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Least_Squares_Circle